# What is the difference between running ./configure -D_GNU_SOURCE and adding the AC_GNU_SOURCE macro to configure.ac?

Tags: c, autotools

I am trying to compile my project but it fails when I don't use ./configure -D_GNU_SOURCE. I want to fix this in the build system and tried defining it in configure.ac, but doesn't solve my make issue.

When I put AC_GNU_SOURCE in configure.ac and run autoconf to generate a new configure script I can see that it adds the line:

```
 $as_echo "#define _GNU_SOURCE 1" >>confdefs.h
```

When I run make it fails to build my files. It succeeds if I run:

```
./configure CFLAGS=-D_GNU_FLAGS
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: (how?) are you including confdefs.h in your project's sources?

Comment: There are process variables in the configure.  Just because you add it to confdefs.h doesn't mean everything is honky dory.  You could edit configure to have -D_GNU_FLAGS as part of CFLAGS.  (Not sure what you are trying to do, or why.)

Comment: exactly how does it fail (what is the exact output?) when you don't have that bit in?